# Programmatically sanity check Linux clock

Tags: linux

I have a production system on JVM/Linux that relies on `System.nanoTime` and `System.currentTimeMillis`. I've been in situations before where NTP completely messed up the slew, so the clock was running much faster or slower than real time (and the slew affects both aforementioned Java methods).

How can I best monitor that `nanoTime` and `currentTimeMillis` are running at close to the correct speed? I would like to periodically measure the deltas in those methods, and compare those to "known" deltas over the same period. What is a reliable source of "known" deltas? C/C++ solutions are fine.

Comment: How do you know that they are not? BTW - NTP tries to keep your time in sync with another clock taking into account network speed. It has to speed/slow things up/down a little to keep the two in sync.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable source of time, especially on a VM, would have to be external to the machine. I assume that you do not have access to specialized hardware (like atomic clocks or GPS receivers), so your next best bet is NTP. Find an NTP server near you, take the a 'before' time via your system clock, get time via NTP, and take an 'after' reading of the clock. Compare the difference between the average of 'before' and 'after' with the NTP value. You should not expect the difference to be zero (your network latency is likely not the same in both directions, etc). Monitor the difference over time. I expect the variation to down out the trend, but if you see the trend increasing (or decreasing) with any degree of confidence, then you may have a messed up clock.

Comment: I guess it does not matter as long as the value is small and constant. Also using JVM for a real time system (i.e. relying on very accurate timing) is probably not a good solution in the first place.

Comment: I don't need a reliable source of time like an atomic clock (expensive, or relies on someone NTP being configured correctly), I just need to know which hardware timers I can trust to not change frequency with NTP (and being off by a few seconds per day is fine, I'm just looking for giant deviations). I've read about rdtsc being invariant, but I was wondering if that was actually appropriate.